# How to insert text from Photoshop (text layer with given name) to Python script (as value of variable), using Python?

Tags: python, photoshop, photoshop-script

Is there any method to get (programmatically with Python) text from the Photoshop text layer, for ex. named `TextToPython` and assign it as a variable in python script?
For example, Photoshop has a text layer "TextToPython" containing the text `Text Sample 1`.
I need to put it into python script as variable 'TextToPythonVar1', using the same python script.
So python variable `TextToPythonVar1 = "Text Sample 1"`

Answer (score 0):

Using advice of xuio (to use psd-tools), after reading [Docs of psd-tools](https://psd-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)  I made some edits to his answer, cause seems he made some mistakes.
My working script is:

```
from psd_tools import PSDImage
psd = PSDImage.open('path/to/psd/file.psd')
for layer in psd:
    layer
TextToPythonVar1 = layer.text
print(TextToPythonVar1)
```

Works only for first text layer in PSD file.
If someone know how to choose which layer to use (using his name, or by number), will appreciate that.